# php code within an html code stored inside a php variable, how can this work?

Tags: php, html, echo

I am currently making a simple website, I have a file called 'functions.php', where I store some simple functions and this piece of code

```
<div id=\"topContactPan\">

<div id=\"topMenuPan\">
  <div id=\"topMenuLeftPan\"></div>

  <div id=\"topMenuMiddlePan\">
<a href= <?Php if(!admin_class::isadmin()){ 
echo "\"userprofile.php\" >User Profile</a></li>";} 
else { echo "\"adminprofile.php\" >Admin</a>"; } ?>
```

I needed to escape all the " so it would interpret properly since this is within a php file, all of this is stored inside a variable $top, so whenever i create a new page of my website, i just echo $top and echo $bottom and theres the top header and bottom footer, only the content is missing.

but with the code above, I wanted one of the links on the navigation bar to switch where is is pointing to depending if the one who is logged in is an admin or a regular user. But it only seems that when I click the link, the header becomes `http://localhost/YMMLS/<?Php`.

Any suggestions? thanks so much

Comment: eval. But why not make it functions, top() and bottom() instead of variables?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using `eval`. Also, why not move the double quotes outside the tags?

Comment: Eval is ok when you know what you are doing. Going by your code, you'l perhaps, open up lots of security holes. Don't use it for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do like this in your functions.php:

```
<?php
function template() {
    ?>
    <div id="topContactPan">

    <div id="topMenuPan">
    <div id="topMenuLeftPan"></div>

    <div id="topMenuMiddlePan">

    <a href="<?php checklink(); ?>"> <?php checkuser(); ?></a>
    <?php   
}

function checklink() {
    if(!admin_class::isadmin()) {
        echo "userprofile.php";
    } else {
        echo "adminprofile.php";
    }
}
function checkuser() {
    if(!admin_class::isadmin()) {
        echo "User Profile";
    } else {
        echo "Admin";
    }
}
?>
```

Then in your file you just include it and call its function :

```
<?php
include('functions.php');
template();
?>
```

It is not the best solution maybe. :D

Answer (score 2):

make 2 files.

header.php and footer.php

inside of each of those write your html as you normally would - then on your index or what ever page just say

```
include('header.php');
<p>YOUR HTML PAGE AND DOC<p>
include('footer.php');
```

No need to go through escaping everything.